# batch - xcopy syntax error? not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

i need a batch script to copy my php files into a xampp folder. The script throws a syntax error and i can't find it. can you please tell me where the error is?

```
cd src/php
if exist c:/xampp (
  xcopy "*.*" "c:\xampp\htdocs\Stentthrombose-API"
)else(
  xcopy "*.*" "d:\xampp\htdoc\Stentthrombose-API\"
)
```

Comment: `)else(` should be `) else (`

Comment: BTW - `/` is a switch-indicator in Winbatch; `\\` is a directory-separator. Sometimes the conversion is done, sometimes not.